# User Level Logic

Tags: php, mysql

I have a project that I am working on and I've been researching about having User Levels and the recommended & secure ways of doing it.
The project will have some more complex stuff like groups, users, pages, chat and I don't want to make some changes now and be required to re-change the logic when I will add the other features.
I would like some advice or help on this, I would appreciate it very much.

The way I was thinking was either

1. Have a table named userlevels (for example) with 3 columns `ID`, `Name`, `Permissions`

   ```
   1, user

   2, Administrator, {"admin": 1}     with json
   ```

OR

2. Have an additional row with permissions in the normal users table, and have a row for example

   ```
   is_admin  [0,1]
   ```

Is it okay to do it like this ? If you have any other ideas for me I would honestly appreciate it very much.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The best way is to use a separate table with permissions so you can easily change/update when necessary. So the first point should be fine.

Comment: A row is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll propose a more normalized solution that should be completely flexible going forward.

1. A table of users:

   ```
   UserID (PK) 
   UserName
   ```
2. A table of permissions

   ```
   PermissionId (PK)
   Permission
   ```
3. A junction table to resolve the many-to-many relationship between users and permissions

   ```
   UserID (FK to users)
   PermissionId (FK to permissions)
   ```

[image]

Comment: PK indicates the Primary Key for the table. FK indicates that the column is a Foreign Key referencing another table.

Comment: something like  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)   and FOREIGN KEY (permission_id) REFERENCES permissions(permission_id) ?

Comment: Thank you very much, Joe. I will try it out and see how it turns out. Cheers